# (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am using the fb graph api to post on fb.

here is my code..

```
include_once("config.php");

$page_id = '2267dsfgsfdsg32';
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$args = array('message' => 'Photo Caption');


 $args = array(
 'access_token'=>"CAADHIv47plHx i changed it nCCGDqEWNQZBZBySZC04xXDyqn0jZB3",
 'message' => 'This photo was uploaded ',
 'name' => 'Product name',
 'caption' => 'Accomplished!',
 'link' => 'http://www.adspace.lk/',
 'picture' => 'http://adspace.lk/assets/img/tmp/banner2.jpg');

 $data = $facebook->api('post', $args);
 print_r($data);
```

i get the error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: post thrown in /home/design/public_html/jksb/fb/inc/base_facebook.php on line 1249
```

can any one help me to fix this error plz...

Comment: There is no post endpoint. The first argument to $facebook->api should be the endpoint you are sending the request to. Like /me or /me/friends or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using no endpoint, `post` is the HTTP method of the request. Try using `/me/photos` as noted on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/photos/#publish

There's also an example here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/uploadphoto/4.0.0

Comment: It is worth noting that I also think Facebook has changed slightly in that it use to accept me/photos but now it must be /me/photos. This caused the 803 error as well.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you either miss to specify all the required fields or your addressing is wrong. So, first off, as I see, you miss an App name on whose behalf you would be sharing the activity on user's activity feed. So, you may first create an App [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/async/create/dialog/). Then, you need to define actions and objects which you would be sharing in the feed. Collectively, you may need to create Custom Stories (if you intend to create custom stories, on the same link I shared; just go to 'Open Graph' option). For predefined stories by facebook, such as video, your post action would be like following. Also, You need to specify the type of object you're sharing, like this:
`$facebook->api($user_id.'/app_name:activity_name','POST',$post_obj);`
where `$post_obj` is `$post_obj = array('other'=>$args)` 
`other` is index for 'video' objects. You may check/change that to the object name you're sharing. This could be 'blog', 'news' or whatever you may create.